# A question about the code for cobweb diagram of Tent function through MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here I am trying to do the Cobweb diagram for Tent function through MATLAB, and here is the code:

```
    function cobweb(f,a,b,x0,N)

    x0 = 0.8; % initial point
    N = 200; % number of iterations
    x = linspace(0,1,1000); % space of x
     
    for i=1:numel(x)
      if 1/2 >= x(i)
        f(i) = 1.5*x(i);
      elseif x(i) >= 1/2
        f(i) = 1.5*(1-x(i));
    end
    end
    

    hold on
    plot(x,f,'k')
    hold on
    plot(x,x,'r')

    xlabel('x(t)')
    ylabel('f(t+1)')

    grid on

    x(1) = x0;

    line([x(1),x(1)],[0,f(x(1))]);
    line([x(1),f(x(1))],[f(x(1)),f(x(1))]);

    for i=1:N
        x(i+1) = f(x(i));
        plot([x(i+1),x(i+1)],[x(i+1),f(x(i+1))]);
        hold on
        plot([x(i+1),f(x(i+1))],[f(x(i+1)),f(x(i+1))]);
    end
    hold off
```

My question is, when I am running the code, MATLAB says:

Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in cobwebplot (line 31)
line([x(1),x(1)],[0,f(x(1))]);

But I don't understand why here it says so, because I didn't find any non-integer indices here. And I tried to replace "line" with "plot" but it is of no use. So can someone help me explain why here it has such error? Thanks!

Comment: `f(x(1))` is `f(0.8)`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but here x(1) is not array indice.

Comment: Yes it is. `f` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

In your initial loop,

```matlab
    for i=1:numel(x)
      if 1/2 >= x(i)
        f(i) = 1.5*x(i);
      elseif x(i) >= 1/2
        f(i) = 1.5*(1-x(i));
    end
    end
```

`f` is used as an array.

In your later line,

```matlab
line([x(1),x(1)],[0,f(x(1))]);
```

after you defined `x0=0.8`, you use `f` as it was a function.

Hence the error.

Pick one or another.

*It would seem as if you need `f(1)` over `f(x(1))` in your plotting. You need to either determine what you use based on your needs. Alternatively, you may ask specific questions on how to use `line`, `plot` etc.*

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Then how should I modify the code?

Comment: @ZYX: Please see the italicized part of my answer. I understand that your question was about how to interpret the error message. What you will do after understanding the error depends on your application and is not a question with a definitive answer as we make StackOverflow questions. If you are unsure how to plot something, feel free to, in a separate question, elaborate what it is that you are trying to plot, etc